# The repeat uses the same values from the previous question. Which of the function contains the error?

Tags: python-2.7

If the user opts to play again, and selects the operation they want to use, the program still uses the operation symbol from the previous game. See the code below.

```
import random

print "Welcome!"

def get_choice():
    print "What are we practicing? \n1. Addition (+) \n2. Subtraction (-) \n3. Multiplication (*) \n4. Division (/)"

    option = raw_input('> ')

    while option != '+' and option != '-' and option != '*' and option != '/':
        print "You typed %r which is not valid. Please enter \'+, -, *,or /\'" %(option)
        option = raw_input('>')
    return option

operation = get_choice()

def ask_question (operation):
    numbers = []
    for y in range(0,2):
        x = random.randint(1,100)
        numbers.append(x)
    num1 = numbers[0]
    num2 = numbers[1]
    print num1, operation, num2
    response = int(raw_input('>'))
    return num1, num2, response

num1, num2, response = ask_question(operation)

def check_response(response):
    if operation == '+':
        answer = num1 + num2
    elif operation == '-':
        answer = num1 - num2
    elif operation == '*':
        answer = num1 * num2
    else:
        answer = num1 / num2

    i = 0
    if response == answer:
        print "Correct!"
    elif response != answer:
        while i < 2:
            print "Wrong! Try again: \n%r + %r" %(num1, num2)
            i += 1
            response = raw_input()
            if response != answer and i >= 2:
                print "Sorry. You run out of chances."

check_response(response)

def repeat():
    while True:
        print "Do you want to play again?"
        again = raw_input('>')
        if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
            get_choice()
            ask_question(operation)
            check_response(response)
        else:
            break   
repeat()
```

See a sample output below.

Welcome!
What are we practicing? 
1. Addition (+) 
2. Subtraction (-) 
3. Multiplication (*) 
4. Division (/)

> +
>   78 + 28
>   106
>   Correct!
>   Do you want to play again?
>   y
>   What are we practicing? 
>   1. Addition (+) 
>   2. Subtraction (-) 
>   3. Multiplication (*)
>
> ### 4. Division (/)
>
> 62 + 85

Comment: It's because you are returning your `option` from `get_choice` but you never set `operation` in `repeat`. So the original `operation` is always used, from `operation = get_choice()`

Comment: Also, try to keep your main execution code away from your functions, it gets pretty confusing when you have code in between function definitions.